# Inverse of cumulative probabilty (CDF) in Julia?

Tags: statistics, julia

If I have a value, such as `0.5` for a standard normal distribution, how do I convert that into a random outcome?

E.g. I am looking for the function `f` such that `f(0.5) = 0.0` for a standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> using Distributions
[ Info: Precompiling Distributions [31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f]

julia> quantile(Normal(), 0.5)
0.0
```

[doc](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/v0.25/univariate/#Statistics.quantile-Tuple%7BUnivariateDistribution,%20Real%7D) says:

> Evaluate the inverse cumulative distribution function at q.